# Canadian (Alberta) Residential Electrical Code

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, code-compliance, recessed-lighting

Is there a homeowners version of the current electrical code for residential wiring in Alberta available at no cost? I’m renovating my kitchen and would be helpful to know the many changes and requirements for budget purposes.

Comment: I also live in Alberta, and always assumed that this would be available from your local permit office? Mind you I hadn't looked into it as we are currently only doing renos that don't require permits (e.g. flooring and paint).

Comment: Electrical code is very technical and not going to be an easy read.  Even if you did read it, it would be very hard to tell what is "new".  I think you might be better served by looking for a summary of changes online or even pay for a consultation from a local, experienced electrician.

Comment: The electrical also *itself says* it is not a how-to manual, and is not written in a format that would lend itself to learning electrical.  They leave that to the marketplace, though realy, electrical is viewed as a trade you apprentice up into.

Comment: Here in the US, you can look at (but not copy) the National Electric Code on-line for free. I woulkd imagine there is something like that for canada as well. But if not, it's a relatively safe bet that if it is in the NEC, it is in the CEC, so one thing you might consider is looking up your questions in the NEC, and assuming the solutions will apply in Canada as well (other than procedural issues like permitting etc.). 
https://www.nfpa.org/NEC/About-the-NEC/Free-online-access-to-the-NEC-and-other-electrical-standards

Comment: A quick look on search engines reveals that the CEC is apparently NOT available in any "free" format whatsoever.